# Inline CSS is not working in email html template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-email, email-client

I am trying to send a custom email to the client. Here I added an anchor tag and styled it as a button but ts not working at all.

```
   string footer = "<div>";
                string footerEnd = "</div>";
                string bid = "<a style=' display: block; width: 115px;height: 25px; background: #2196F3;padding: 10px;text - align: center;border - radius: 5px;color: white; font - weight: bold;line - height: 25px; ' href ='www.google.com' >Create Bid</a>";
                string footerData = "<p>Thank you <be> ..P Systems</p>";
                footer = footer += bid; 
                footer += footerData;
                footer += footerEnd;
                mailBody += Header;
                mailBody += body;
                mailBody += footer;
                mail.Body = mailBody;
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.stackmail.com", 
                587);
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new 
                System.Net.NetworkCredential("abc@glee.com", 
                "******");
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
                mail.From = new MailAddress("abc@glee.com");
                mail.To.Add("xyz@gmail.com");

                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

And The result is:

[image: Result]

Comment: Can you share the html of final email that is being sent? You can remove sensitive data. What you have shared is not enough information.

Comment: i edited the code. Now I hope so that you may understand the scenario. Thank you

Comment: As @r2018 said, can we see the HTML result of at code and also what email client are you previewing this email in? There are some like Outlook which won't allow you style as <a> tag in the way you are doing.

Comment: Have you tried this without the spacing between css names? Try `font-weight: bold;` instead of `font - weight: bold;`. Without more code, I can't tell what is happening with the overall html code.

Comment: thank you @gwally, i removed the spaces and it started working as I wanted.